# Google Web Toolkit Evaluate String

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying out google web toolkit for the first time by making a simple calculator app. I have a string I need to evaluate, for example "123+32". How can I do this with GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because GWT is java, you'll have to split your string, in `123` `+` `32`, then turn the numeric strings into actual integers (`Integer.parseInt`) and then based on the operator string actually do the sum.

I'm guessing you could also use [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) and do a javascript `eval` on the string, but remember that's very dangerous unless you validate the user input, as they might end up running arbitrary code.

Comment: You're definitely right, you could use JS, but you'd be much safer to use the integer types to ensure somebody isn't trying to mess with you.  This way it'll fail if the string contains anything other than numbers.

Comment: Agreed completely @Chris Thompson.